# Можно ли авторизоваться на сайте скопировав куки?

Tags: node.js, cookie, xss

Начал знакомиться с механизмом сессий возник следующий вопрос. В куках хранится ключ сессии конкретного пользователя, значит ли это, что для входа например в vk с другого устройства достаточно просто скопировать куки ?

Answer (score 0):

Постоянно так делаю, только он еще и юзерагенрт проверяет.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от реализации сессии на сервере. Если в сессии хранится только логин, ключ и дата создания то можно, но обычно к информации в сессии добавляют ip, страну, ОС, браузер и вообще всё на что фантазии хватит для дополнительной идентификации. При несовпадении чего либо авторизация отклоняется